# Get all tweets that are all caps

Tags: regex, search, twitter, case-sensitive

Using the Twitter API, how would you retrieve all updates that are in all CAPS?

Comment: retrieve all, filter all caps

Comment: Do you have some code for that sir?

Comment: If you want code, it would be good to know in what language//enviroment.

Comment: I would be using PHP. I was wondering if there was a param in the API that allowed it.

Answer (score 3):

Building pseudo code from SilentGhost's comment:

```
1. Retrieve all tweets
2. foreach tweet
    3. if (tweet.ToUpper() == tweet) then 
          4. Tweet Is All Caps
```

Use string matching instead of regex with this type of problem.